# Subclass object returns nil - Typhoon

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am using Typhoon Framework for Dependency injection in iOS.

I have two classes Class A and Class B. Class B is a subclass of Class A. Class A is singletion.

```
- (id)classAObject{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[ClassA class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition){
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeLazySingleton;
        }];
}

- (id)classBObject{
     return [TyphoonDefinition withParent:[self classAObject] class:[ClassB class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

}];
}
```

In class B, i am inheriting class A.

```
@interface Class B: Class A{
}
```

whenever i try to get the classBObject, i am getting nil.

```
@interface classB:NSObject{
}
```

But when i inherit from NSObject, i am getting the value.

what i am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: It's really strange, but I wrote the same code and it works

Comment: Can you show the code where you're getting classes from assembly

Comment: In class C, i am trying to access Class B,  id object = [_assembly classBObject]; //assembly is not nil. Does this helps?

Comment: Did you activate assembly?

Comment: i am not activating explicitly.  Even if i try like this,  [_assembly activate];, i am getting crash  on this line "[NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"No component matching id '%@'.", key];" //key is activate. Do i need to activate explicitly?

Comment: But how it works when i am subclassing from NSObject instead of Class A.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127472/discussion-between-nikita-ermolenko-and-iphone-guy).

Answer (score 0):

In my base class, i was using the following code which causes the issue.

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone { 
@synchronized(self) { 
if (sharedManager == nil) { 
sharedManager = [super allocWithZone:zone]; 
return sharedManager; // assignment and return on first allocation 
} 
} 
return nil; // on subsequent allocation attempts return nil 
}
```

It worked when i remove the above code.